# Nuxt npm js package [Missing stack frames]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, plugins, nuxt.js

I am trying to use [format-unicorn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-unicorn) npm package in my Nuxt app. But after importing it inside my Vue page I get the following errors:

```
Client: Missing stack frames
Server: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.currencyFormat.formatUnicorn is not a function"
```

### Initial approach

The following approach **should** work according to the [plugins documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins):

> Another way to use `package` without installing the module is by importing `package` direct in the `<script>` tag.

```js
// Product.vue
<template>
  <div class="product">
    <p>Price: {{ localizedPrice }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
require('format-unicorn')

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currencyFormat: '{c}{p}',
      currency: '$',
      price: 12.99
    }
  },
  computed: {
    localizedPrice: {
      get() {
        return this.currencyFormat.formatUnicorn({c: this.currency, p:this.price})
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately this approach gives me an error:
`Missing stack frames` (and no other useful info).

And in the node console: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.currencyFormat.formatUnicorn is not a function"`

But what is weird, is that this page actually opens without any error if I **navigate** with `Nuxtlink` there. But as soon as I hit refresh, the error persists.

### Utilizing plugins approach

By creating `format-unicorn.js` file inside `plugins` directory I was still getting the same error:

```js
//// plugins/format-unicorn.js
require('format-unicorn');
```

```js
//// nuxt.config.js
// ...
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/format-unicorn.js'
//  applying mode: 'client' or 'server' doesn't help as well
  ],
// ...
```

### Naive plugins appproach

I wanted to know if it's going to work at all, so I just pasted code from package repo there **(And it worked)** :

```js
//// plugins/format-unicorn.js
String.prototype.formatUnicorn = function () {
  let str = this.toString()

  if (arguments.length) {
    const type = typeof arguments[0]
    const args = type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0]

    for (const arg in args) str = str.replace(new RegExp(`\\{${arg}\\}`, 'gi'), args[arg])
  }

  return str
}
```

```js
//// nuxt.config.js
// ...
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/format-unicorn.js'
  ],
// ...
```

### Conclusion

By this point you probably realize I am not satisfied with naive approach since I want to extend my app with 3rd party packages in future. And my question here is what am I doing wrong? Is there anything special in trying to extend a prototype from Nuxt plugin or I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

My nuxt error-message "Missing stack frames" was gone by stopping

```
npm run dev
```

with **Control-C** and start again.

Answer (score 0):

My nuxt error-message "Missing stack frames" happened with project that uses node 12. It resolved with next steps:

1. Stop with Control+C
2. Change to node version you need. You can skip this step.

```
nvm use 12
```

3. Run

```
yarn cache clean
```

4. Re-install node modules with:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
yarn install --ignore-engines
```

5. Run:

```
yarn dev
```